# What would happen if 'more than one RESPONSE' is received for 'a single REQUEST' which was BROADCAST to the Sawtooth Network node peers?

Tags: architecture, hyperledger, p2p, system-design, hyperledger-sawtooth

Below statement is from this [documentation](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/architecture/validator_network.html).

> In the case where a node could not satisfy the request, the node stores who it received the request from and BROADCASTs the request on to its peers. If that node receives a SEND message with the response to the request, it forwards the SEND message back to the original requester.

**Let's assume:**

- nodes: A, B, C, D and Y.
- `A is peered to B and Y`
- `B is peered to C and D`
- *NOTE: A is `not peered with C and D`.*

A sends REQUEST to B.
B could NOT satisfy the request. Hence, B BROADCASTs the REQUEST to C and D.

First, C replies with a RESPONSE to B. B forwards the RESPONSE back to the original requester.

Next, D replies with a RESPONSE to B, as well.

**Question:**

***What does B do? Forward the RESPONSE from D, as well, to A?***

If *yes*, can A accept 'more than one RESPONSE' for 'a single REQUEST' that it had originally sent out?.

If *no*, does B discords the successive RESPONSEs, after the very first RESPONSE?

Answer (score 0):

If B is peered to A, C, and D, there is only one blockchain, as the nodes are all connected to each other.

Comment: Your assumption of `B is peered to A, C, and D` is different than the `original assumption in the question`. Even if there are 1000 nodes in the network, it's quite possible that there exists a scenario: `A is peered to B` and `B is peered to C and D`, NOTE: A is `not peered with C and D`.

So scenario of the question is different.